# Open port 12489 for nrpe

Tags: debian, nagios, nrpe

I'm learning a little bit of nagios and unix(buster), and im getting an error related with monitoring CPU LOAD and MEMORY USAGE

The feedback I get from the monitor is

```
connect to address 192.168.1.94 and port 12489: Connection refused
```

could not fetch information from server

So I went to the client machine and ran netstat -an, and the port doesnt seem to be listening.

I tried to add some rules on iptables, did some rules for port 12489 on TCP

the port was there on "ACCEPT tcp -- anywhere anywhere tcp dpt:12489"

```
sudo iptables-save
```

what am I missing? the machines are in the same local network

am im missing some configuration or plugin?

Thank you

Comment: Beyond allowing incoming traffic on the port, you need something listening to that port. Start nrpe. Usually it is on port 5666, but perhaps you've changed that.

Comment: no, i guess the monitor is set to 12489 while nrpe is set for 5666, its confusing